# In nightwatch how to make all functions / commands execute sequentially

Tags: nightwatch.js

Like in jquery, we have option like `async: false`.

How to make all functions and commands to be executed sequentially?  i.e. synchronous in nightwatch, so that it works like normal execution flow without jumping to next command , by not waiting asynchronsously for webdriver commands like click, etc.

Comment: Please post sample code .